# WideCharToMultiByte produces Chinese characters when writing to registery

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, widechar, multibyte-functions

I have this ancient bit of code for an IE BHO, and I'm trying to store some data for it.

I'm trying this approach:

```
// key is an LPWSTR provided as a method parameter
// sValue is an LPWSTR provided as a method parameter

HKEY hKey = NULL;

HRESULT hRes = IEGetWriteableHKCU(&hKey);

if (SUCCEEDED(hRes) && hKey)
{
    CHAR mbStr[2048] = { 0 };
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, sValue, lstrlen(sValue), mbStr, 2048, NULL, NULL);

     // Skipping error checking for now
    RegSetKeyValue(hKey, L"A\\Key\\I\\Can\\Write\\To", key, REG_SZ, mbStr, (DWORD)strnlen_s(mbStr, 2048));

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

The value I enter is written, and can be successfully read. However, when I look at it in regedit, I see Chinese characters. This will make troubleshooting challenging, so I would like to have the characters written correctly.

This is obviously some sort of encoding issue, but I can't seem to find the magic bullet to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Strings in the registry are always encoded as utf-16, never utf-8.  Since you already have a utf-16 encoded string (LPWSTR), you should not be calling WideCharToMultiByte() at all.

Comment: @HansPassant right, but a straight cast to BYTE* also yielded Chinese characters, which is why I thought conversion was necessary

Comment: The caller of this method is then the likely source of the bug, doing it wrong in a similar way you did it wrong here.  Use the debugger, look at the LPWSTR argument and verify that it actually contains 16-bit character codes.

Comment: @HansPassant the source is an WCHAR[2048] which is populated by user input from a text box in a dialog. Looking at the values in a debugger shows correct values all the way up and down the stack. Also, the values are written and read correctly - code functions as it should.

Comment: Also, looking at the individual character codes, they seem to comply with UTF-16 (e.g. i == 105, two \0 at the end).

Comment: @HansPassant at the end, you were right to say no conversion was necessary. I had other issues, which I found after I followed your advice. If you post an answer, I will accept it.